# Restoring Mac HD to a Single Volume

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility

I had originally done a Bootcamp install in the past but had to uninstall it for unspecified reasons, which I mistakenly did so using the Disk Utility in Recovery Mode. However, I'm now stuck with an unwanted Volume that's labeled as a "PCI-Express". For demonstration purposes, here is my volume log from entering 'diskutil list' into the Command tool.

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                         28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                28.0 GB    disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Machintosh HD           999.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS TOSHIBA                 499.8 GB   disk2s2
```

And a screenshot...

[image]

What I want to do is completely remove this volume and restore everything to a singular non-Fusion drive (it was created as a Fusion Drive when I installed Bootcamp). Any tips will be useful, even if it means going to Disk Utility and wiping everything clean again.

Thanks.

Comment: What I would do is make a 1TB fusion of disk0 and disk1.  Instructions can be found at https://www.macworld.com/article/2014011/storage-drives/how-to-make-your-own-fusion-drive.html , but as you dislike the fusion, this does not answer your question

Comment: No, I want to merge disk 0 and 1 together as one, thus restoring the two as a singular drive.

Comment: Does **Machintosh HD** contain any data/your system?

Comment: Yes, I currently have High Sierra installed at the moment.

Comment: If you have a time machine backup, follow the instructions listed in my previous comment.  It will combine the two drives to one single Fusion drive.  I'd make the amount of space available as 1TB.  If you do not have a Time Machine backup, make one and follow the above.

Comment: Right, well I've followed the guide you add, and thankfully, the HD is now restored as a singular drive, with the singluar volume listed under a Fusion Drive container. The problem I'm having now is to do with a Time Machine restore. Before I started messing around with Bootcamp, I had made a Time Machine backup, but at the moment it's not letting me restore it. I'm assuming this is because my Mac HD was in APFS format when I made it, but I'm not 100% sure. Is there anyway I can format my Mac HD in APFS? Doing so in Disk Utility just results in failure, but Mac OS Extended works fine.

Comment: Still stuck on the backup issue, but otherwise my Mac is runinng fine again and my drive is more or less back to normal. Thanks Matthew.